# Python script won't read() after urlopen from localhost gae dev server -- Connection Reset By Peer

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, urllib2, urllib

So I'm running the Google App Engine development server (Java) on localhost.  I'm trying to retrieve a URL using Python 2.7 urllib.urlopen.  The initial retrieve works, but then when I try to call read() or readlines() I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "./getMap.py", line 6, in <module>
    lst = f.readlines()
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 513, in readlines
    line = self.readline()
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 445, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 552, in read
    s = self.fp.read(amt)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 378, in read
    data = self._sock.recv(left) 
socket.error: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
```

The browser works, wget works.  Problem occurs with both urllib and urllib2.  Here's the code:

```
import urllib2

f = urllib2.urlopen("http://localhost:8080/default.jsp")
lst = f.readlines()

for a in lst:
    print a
```

Strangely, I can print out the first line of the file using readline() -- I just can't get the *whole* file.  I get the sense that maybe Python is "lazily" not requesting the entire contents of the URL until I request it via readlines(), and by then the app engine dev server has overzealously closed the connection.  But I could be totally wrong about that.

I tried researching this problem but I didn't see anything applicable.  Most of the Google hits I'm seeing surround random, intermittant timing issues (this isn't an intermittant problem, it's reliable) or proxy/firewall issues (nothing like that going on here).

Assuming my theory is correct -- is there a way to tell urlopen to get the whole response right away, as wget and the browser seem to be doing?  Or is there a way to tell the GAE dev server to chill out and not close the connection so quickly?  I'd rather not dive into lower-level python socket stuff if I don't have to.

thanks

p.s. clarification: the python script is just running from the command line and trying to make a connection to the GAE dev server, which is running on the same box.  I'm NOT trying to connect to the GAE dev server from itself or something weird like that, the GAE server is running Java, not Python.  What I'm actually trying to do here is this: my GAE web app has some web services and I'm writing a batch script to get/post to those webservices, so that when I need to reset/clear the data store (example: data gets corrupted) I can use this python script to back up the data first, then I erase the data store, and then use the script again to load that data back in.

UPDATE: so I tried a few more tests.  Python has no trouble reading any HTML file served by the GAE dev server.  However any JSP, even the simplest "hello world" JSP, fails to read with the same "connection reset by peer" error.  I'll try updating to the 1.6.1 version of the GAE SDK, I have to do that anyway at some point, might as well be now.  Hopefully it will fix this.

Comment: Does `f.read()` yield the whole file?

Comment: you can always call wget from java with Runtime.exec(), if nothing else works...

Comment: Two trivial test cases against an HttpServlet and a .jsp file both work. I'm using App Engine 1.6.1 and Python 2.7.

What are you doing in the jsp? If you make a trivial one that doesn't do anything, does it work?

Comment: Are you running this inside App Engine? You shouldn't ever use `print` from within a WSGI app, and if you are using App Engine, it'd be easier to use urlfetch.

Comment: f.read() crashes just like readlines() 
....
I thought about using wget, that's my last resort if I can't get this working
....
I'm on app engine 1.6.0 and 2.7. I'm querying the data store in the jsp, I can try a trivial example, that's a good idea
....
no I'm not running this inside app engine, see my clarification above
....
thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I cannot see anything wrong with your python code and have no idea what might be wrong with your Java GAE setup I instead propose a different take on the problem.

You mention that you basically want to send GET/POST requests to your server and save/later read the content and that command line tools like wget works. I suggest you use a bash script and curl and python for the cases when you need to do more advanced text editing.

```
curl http://localhost:8080/default.jsp > default.bak
... wipe db ...
data = $(cat default.bak)
curl -X "POST" -d "backup=$data" http://localhost:8080/default_restore.jsp
```

If you need to edit the data before sending it you can use python to either read from default.bak or by piping it to stdin

```
data = $(cat default.bak)
python your_script.py $data

curl http://localhost:8080/default.jsp | python yourscript.py > default.bak
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously a bit late to the party, but I had exactly the same issue, and I solved it by swapping out urllib for httplib:

```
import httplib
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection('localhost:8080')

# get the current image and save to file
url = 'default.jsp'
conn.request("GET", url)
response = conn.getresponse()
if response.status == 404:
    return None
img_file = open("out.jpg",'wb')
img_file.write(response.read())
img_file.close()
response.close()
conn.close()
```

I don't know why this works, I can only assume that httplib is slightly better behaved than urllib